# Game rendering in monochrome for self driving AI test?

Tags: image-processing, artificial-intelligence, rendering, render

As you might already know, processing a monochrome image(B&W) is much easier than an RGB image for image processing.

I'm working on a self-driving AI right now. It is still in **the early development stage**.

The game I choose is **The Crew (2014)**  because of realistic driving, realistic graphics, open-world environments and online mod. Also relatively old game so must be easier to run in higher resolution (***if needed***).
I'm planning to log in with a different account so I can bully the AI as a different car on the road. Therefore I can test accident prevention capabilities.

I was planning to render the game in B&W for AI but actually I don't really know how to do that.
I think I can encode the output as B&W after rendering in full colours but,
Can I render it in B&W natively?

If I can, will rendering in monochrome improve FPS over RGB rendering?

I don't really know much about rendering (especially in games) but I think it should improve performance.
Because the game will be rendering on my old GPU (GTX 670) while AI uses GTX 1080 TI, I don't want to get another card just for game running.